# LSApplicationLaunchProhibited when trying to upload a sticker extension via Xcode 8 beta 3

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, xcode8-beta3

I am getting this error when trying to upload/validate/export to iTunes Connect, looks like it cannot seem to find LSApplicationLaunchProhibited in the Info.plist file.

How it can be fixed?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3q88.png